EF Core 6 & SQL Server & .NET 6 : navigation property error
I try to migrate from NHibernate to EF Core. I added a repository pattern and migrate repo per repo. No I run into problems with navigation properties.

System.InvalidOperationException: The property or navigation 'ReadJob' cannot be added to the entity type 'ProductRead' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'ProductRead'.

Model builder looks like this:
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductRead>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).IsRequired(false);

    entity.Property(e => e.AbsDeviation)
        .HasColumnName("absDeviation")
        .HasComputedColumnSql("(abs([Quantity]-[ExpectedQuantity]))", false);

    entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasMaxLength(255);

    entity.Property(e => e.NegativeDeviation)
        .HasColumnName("negativeDeviation")
        .HasComputedColumnSql("(case when [ExpectedQuantity]>[Quantity] then [Quantity]-[ExpectedQuantity] else (0) end)", false);

    entity.Property(e => e.PositiveDeviation)
        .HasColumnName("positiveDeviation")
        .HasComputedColumnSql("(case when [Quantity]>[ExpectedQuantity] then [Quantity]-[ExpectedQuantity] else (0) end)", false);

    entity.Property(e => e.Sku).HasMaxLength(36);

    entity.Property(e => e.Version)
        .IsRowVersion()
        .IsConcurrencyToken();
    
    entity.HasOne(e => e.ReadJob)
        .WithMany(e => e.ProductReads)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReadJobId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_ProductReads_ReadJobId_ReadJob_Id")
        .IsRequired(false)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Created, "IX_ProductReads_Created_Quantity_ReadJobId_Sku")
        .HasFillFactor(90);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.ReadJob, "IX_ProductReads_ReadJobId_CreatedSkuQuantityExpectedQuantityImageUrlNoStockTransferVersion")
        .HasFillFactor(90);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.ReadJob, "IX_ProductReads_ReadJobId_Incl_Sku")
        .HasFillFactor(80);

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ReadJob, e.Sku }, "IX_ProductReads_ReadJobId_Sku_cover")
        .HasFillFactor(80);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<ReadJob>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assignment, e.ReadType, e.State }, "IX_ReadJobs_AssignmentId_ReadType_State")
        .HasFillFactor(80);

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ReadType, e.Completed }, "IX_ReadJobs_ReadType_Completed_Created_UserId")
        .HasFillFactor(90);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.State, "IX_ReadJobs_State_includes")
        .HasFillFactor(90);

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.UserId, e.ReadType, e.Completed, e.State }, "IX_ReadJobs_UserId_ReadType_Completed_State_includes")
        .HasFillFactor(90);

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.UserId, e.State }, "IX_ReadJobs_UserId_State_cover")
        .HasFillFactor(90);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Assignment, "NonClusteredIndex-20230503-081413")
        .HasFillFactor(80);

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.State, e.UserId }, "UX_ReadJobs_AssignmentId_IsCompleted_filtered")
        .IsUnique()
        .HasFilter("([State]='InProgress')")
        .HasFillFactor(85);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Assignment, "idx_ReadJob_Cover")
        .HasFillFactor(80);

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ReadType, e.State }, "idx_readtype_state")
        .HasFillFactor(90);

    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

    entity.Property(e => e.AssignmentId).IsRequired(false);

    entity.Ignore(e => e.ProductReads);


    entity.Property(e => e.ReadType)
        .HasMaxLength(20)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (ReadType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReadType), v));

    entity.Property(e => e.State)
        .HasMaxLength(255)
        .IsRequired(true)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (ReadJobState)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReadJobState), v));

    entity.Property(e => e.Version)
        .IsRowVersion()
        .IsConcurrencyToken();

    entity.Ignore(e => e.Assignment);
    entity.HasOne(e => e.Assignment)
        .WithMany(e => e.ReadJobs)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.AssignmentId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_ReadJob_Assignment");


});

ProductRead class:
public class ProductRead : EntityBase<Guid>
{
     public ProductRead()
     {
         this.ProductEntries = new List<ProductEntry>();
     }

     public virtual Guid? ReadJobId { get; set; }
     public virtual ReadJob ReadJob { get; set; }

     public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }

     public virtual string Sku { get; set; }

     public virtual int? Quantity { get; set; }

     public virtual int ExpectedQuantity { get; set; }

     public virtual bool NoStockTransfer { get; set; }

     public virtual int? Deviation
     {
         get
         {
             if (this.Quantity != null)
             {
                 return this.Quantity.Value - this.ExpectedQuantity;
             }

             return null;
         }
     }        

     public virtual IList<ProductEntry> ProductEntries { get; protected set; }

     public virtual string ImageUrl { get; set; }
     public virtual int? AbsDeviation { get; }
     public virtual int? PositiveDeviation { get; }
     public virtual int? NegativeDeviation { get; }
}

ReadJob class:
public class ReadJob : EntityBase<Guid> 
{
    public ReadJob()
    {
        this.ProductReads = new List<ProductRead>();
    }

    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Completed { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Started { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ReadJobState State { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid? AssignmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProductRead> ProductReads { get; set; }
    public virtual ReadType ReadType { get; set; }
}

I checked all but what am I missing?

Do you have duplicate configuration in modelBuilder.Entity<ReadJob>( ...?

You may already have a FK in the database for this navigation ? Or are these entirely new tables ?

What is ProductRead's primary key? Also, try to use ReadJobId (not ReadJob) in the HasIndex calls. Side note, why do you have two indexes on ReadJob alone? The names suggest that you forgot included properties.

@ JeremyLakeman i added the ReadJob modelBuilder.
@ DarkkL no are not new tables. As I'm migrating from nhibernate, all constraints keys etc. are already existing.
@ GertArnold ProductRead's  PK is ProductReadId Which is a Guid

modelBuilder configuration order matters. Maybe your model is already configured (perhaps automatically by conventions because some other entity references ProductRead) ?
